# Need an Alternative Optimization Formulation

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

The original problem is: 
$$\max\limits_{x,y} ~ \min\{\min\{a(x,y),b(x,y)\}+\min\{c(x,y),d(x,y)\},e(x,y)\}$$

Can it be written as 
$$\max\limits_{x,y} ~~ T$$
with constraints
$$t_1+t_2  \geq T; ~e(x,y)  \geq T;~a(x,y)  \geq t_1;~b(x,y)  \geq t_1;~c(x,y)  \geq t_2;~d(x,y)  \geq t_2 
$$
or there any easier way? To become a convex problem, what are the conditions for constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reformulation is correct. For the problem to be convex, a,b,c,d,e each need to be jointly concave in (x,y).

Comment: Thanks @Lin confirming this.